# Spring 2.1.0.M4 rabbitmq declare queues and bind them to listeners in runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Let's say I have a declared listener:

[Listener.java](https://github.com/ThePinkPanther/rabbitmq-test/blob/master/src/main/java/test/Listener.java)

```
@RabbitListener(id = "test listener 1")
    public String test2(String req) {
        return req + " result";
}
```

I'm trying to expose it via queue during runtime:

[ListenerTest.java](https://github.com/ThePinkPanther/rabbitmq-test/blob/master/src/test/java/test/ListenerTest.java)

```
Queue declaredQueue = new Queue("new.queue", false);

admin.declareQueue(declaredQueue);

SimpleMessageListenerContainer listener = (SimpleMessageListenerContainer) 
            registry.getListenerContainer("test listener 1");
listener.addQueues(declaredQueue);
```

And then I try message the newly declared queue :

```
String result = template.convertSendAndReceiveAsType("new.queue", "req", ParameterizedTypeReference.forType(String.class));
```

But it just times out and returns null.

When I inspect the listener in debugger I can't see any consumers bound to the new queue [image]

You can find by rabbit config [here](https://github.com/ThePinkPanther/rabbitmq-test/blob/master/src/main/java/test/RabbitConfig.java) and the rest of the source to test this [here](https://github.com/ThePinkPanther/rabbitmq-test).

It's worth to note that this exact setup works in spring boot version **2.0.5.RELEASE** so it might be a bug. I need to find a way to reinitialize the consumers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the 2.1.0 release `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` no longer overrides `AbstractMessageListenerContainer#addQueues` which causes `SimpleMessageListenerContainer#queuesChanged` to not be invoked (likely a bug). However `SimpleMessageListenerContainer#addQueueNames` is overrided and working. So this  either has to be changed to

```
SimpleMessageListenerContainer listener = (SimpleMessageListenerContainer) 
            registry.getListenerContainer("test listener 1");
listener.addQueueNames(declaredQueue.getName());
```

Or `queuesChanged` has to be called manually

```
SimpleMessageListenerContainer listener = (SimpleMessageListenerContainer) 
            registry.getListenerContainer("test listener 1");
listener.addQueues(declaredQueue);
Method method = SimpleMessageListenerContainer.class.getDeclaredMethod("queuesChanged");
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding queues at runtime will cause the container to recycle its consumers (the equivalent of stopping and restarting the container). See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java#L687 This is due to the way the consumer is designed; each consumer thread consumes from multiple queues.

Changing the consumer count does not restart all consumers; see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java#L168

The new [DirectMessageListenerContainer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#choose-container) does not need to restart its consumers when queues are added (there is at least one consumer per queue).

However, it does not support dynamic concurrency scaling.

Comment: DirectMessageListenerContainer was not used here at all, listeners are the implementation of SimpleMessageListenerContainer, does that mean that it's supposed to restart it's consumers?

Comment: I was just suggesting that, if restarting the consumers concerns you, you can use a DMLC instead. Adding queues to the SMLC should automatically restart the consumers; turn on DEBUG logging to verify.

Comment: that's the whole point of this question, after the spring update `SimpleMessageListenerContainer#addQueues` no longer refreshes the consumers, please see the updated answer I posted

Comment: Oh, I see; yes; looks like a bug; however, `addQueueNames()` should work.

Comment: I've been looking for a way to report it, thanks for raising a ticket

Comment: spring-rabbit 2.1.0.RELEASE is in maven central with the fix; it will be incorporated into Boot 2.1.0.RC1 (due tomorrow)